# R data.table check if a row exists in another data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have two `data.table`s like so:

```
tests

id | test | score
=================
 1 |    1 |    90
 1 |    2 |   100
 2 |    1 |    70
 2 |    2 |    80
 3 |    1 |   100
 3 |    2 |    95

cheaters

id | test | score
=================
 1 |    2 |   100
 3 |    1 |   100
 3 |    2 |    95
```

Say I now want to include a boolean column in all_scores to tell whether that particular test was cheated on, so the output would be like this:

```
tests

id | test | score | cheat
=========================
 1 |    1 |    90 | FALSE
 1 |    2 |   100 |  TRUE
 2 |    1 |    70 | FALSE
 2 |    2 |    80 | FALSE
 3 |    1 |   100 |  TRUE
 3 |    2 |    95 |  TRUE
```

Is there an easy way to do this? The tables are keyed on `id` and `test`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create the `cheat` column with initial value of `FALSE`, then join with cheaters, and update `cheat` column to `TRUE` when there's match:

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(tests), id, test)
setkey(setDT(cheaters), id, test)

tests[, cheat := FALSE][cheaters, cheat := TRUE]

tests
#   id test score cheat
#1:  1    1    90 FALSE
#2:  1    2   100  TRUE
#3:  2    1    70 FALSE
#4:  2    2    80 FALSE
#5:  3    1   100  TRUE
#6:  3    2    95  TRUE
```

Or without setting the keys, use `on` parameter to specify the columns to join on:

```
setDT(tests)
setDT(cheaters)
tests[, cheat := FALSE][cheaters, cheat := TRUE, on = .(id, test)]

tests
#   id test score cheat
#1:  1    1    90 FALSE
#2:  1    2   100  TRUE
#3:  2    1    70 FALSE
#4:  2    2    80 FALSE
#5:  3    1   100  TRUE
#6:  3    2    95  TRUE
```